# Getting latitude and longitude from server using PHP

Tags: php, android

I am trying to build an Android app which queries a server to get the latitude and longitude for the given destination. However there seems to be an error in my PHP code as it shows the following error when I input the address in the web browser.

```
Notice: Undefined variable: destination in C:\xampp\htdocs\serverfiles\btc.php on line 6
{"result":[{"latitude":null,"longitude":null}]}
```

This is my btc.php file:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
$id  = $_GET['destination'];
$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "bustrack");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM updates WHERE destination='".$destination."'";
$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$res = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
$result = array();
array_push($result,array(
"latitude"=>$res['latitude'],
"longitude"=>$res['longitude'],
)
);
echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
}
```

Comment: _"Notice: Undefined variable: destination"_ Well... where did you define it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements as described in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: change this `$id  = $_GET['destination'];` to this `$destination  = $_GET['destination'];`

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out Alex!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM updates WHERE destination='".$destination."'";`
The variable `$destination` does not exist. You need to declare it before using it. I believe the variable `$id` is what you want, looking to your code.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is that you never assign `$destination` a variable:

```
$id  = $_GET['destination'];
$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "bustrack");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM updates WHERE destination='".$destination."'";
```

You should do this:

```
$id  = $_GET['destination'];
$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "bustrack");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM updates WHERE destination='".$id."'";
```